# script freezes after putting many items in a Queue

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, freeze

This very small script freezes after execution:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
q = Queue()
for x in range(10000):
    q.put("hello")
print "ok"
```

It prints "ok" correctly, but then just doesn't finish and I have to manually kill the process. I checked the output of `q.full()` and it always returns `False`.
If I add a second loop that gets all the items out of the queue it ends correctly:

```
for x in range(10000):
    q.get()
```

If I reduce the number to 1000, it also ends correctly. So what is the problem here? Is there some limit that I don't know of or do I misunderstand something fundamental about Queues?

**EDIT**

The same happens if I use a pipe instead of a queue:

```
output_p, input_p = Pipe()
for x in range(10000):
    input_p.send("hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious why it doesn't terminate but this gives a hint:

> `close()`
>   Indicate that no more data will be put on this queue by the current process. The background thread will quit once it has flushed all buffered data to the pipe. This is called automatically when the queue is garbage collected

That means the code above creates a background thread to handle the queue. When the code ends, Python tries to close the queue. The queue handler will try to flush the queue but there is no recipient (a `Process`) and so it hangs.

I'd expect an exception, though. Especially since <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks! I actually managed to make it work with the help of `cancel_join_thread()`. I still have no idea why it happens at that arbitrary looking number though.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work using `cancel_join_thread` ([manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues)):

> **Warning:** As mentioned above, if a child process has put items on a
> queue (and it has not used JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread), then
> that process will not terminate until all buffered items have been
> flushed to the pipe.
>
> This means that if you try joining that process
> you may get a deadlock unless you are sure that all items which have
> been put on the queue have been consumed. Similarly, if the child
> process is non-daemonic then the parent process may hang on exit when
> it tries to join all its non-daemonic children.

This doesn't explain however why it happens with 10000 items and not with 1000 items. So I would be curious to know more about it and maybe someone can go more into detail about this.

Comment: There is a 4KB buffer between processes. Maybe 1000 items still fit into the buffer?

Comment: @AaronDigulla Ok, good to know, but I'm not sure if that can be the case, since the five characters would occupy (at least) 5 bytes. So this should already add up to 5000 bytes which is already more than the buffer. It also still works with 2000 items (10,000 bytes = 9.8 KB).

Comment: Plus the objects will probably be pickled, too, which would make them even bigger. I guess someone has to look at the code to see what it actually does.